# Accessing mmap'd memory causes hang

Tags: c, mmap

When I go to try and edit a segment of shared memory my program hangs.
I am trying to create a shared memory segment that holds a string of up to 20 characters (not include \0)

```
char** mem;
mem = mmap(NULL, 20, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
char* new = getNewString();
strncpy(*mem, new, strlen(new));
```

The program hangs on strncpy. made my own loop to do the same as strncpy and it hangs when I try and set the first character.

If I had some sort of error I could do more, but I'm stumped.

Comment: I suggest you start by reading [the `mmap` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). It doesn't return a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Also think about what would happen if the string you copy is longer than 20 characters.

Comment: I had *mem = mmap(...) but it segfaults.. so I guess the problem would be that instead as my "fix" isn't correct. I've fixed the issue though that stems from - basically I thought I needed a char** to store the string with mmap but I don't. Thanks :)

Comment: You get a crash on `*mem = mmap(...)` because `mem` doesn't point anywhere, so dereferencing the pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Can you please tell us *why* you declared `mem` as a pointer to a pointer to `char`?

Comment: I edited my above comment. Basically wrong idea on how mmap gets memory.

Comment: If your compiler can compile C++ files, then the variable name 'new' should be causing a compiler error to be displayed.  You do have something like -Wall  in your compile statement?